# How to create a wordpress post using array values?

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity, gravity-forms-plugin

i am using this code to create a post in DWQA plugin? but, my  theme editer is going to die. what's the problem i am facing?
function my_pre_save_post( $post_id ) {

```
// check if this is to be a new post
if( $post_id != 'new' )
{
    return $post_id;
}

// Create a new post
$post = array(

    'post_content'=> $post_content,
    'post_title'  => $post_title,
     'post_author' => $post_author,
    'post_category' => $post_category,
    'post_type'  => 'dwqa-question',
    'post_status'  => 'draft',
    'post_date'  => 'date_created',
    'show_in_menu' => 'post-new.php?post_type=dwqa-question',

);

// insert the post
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $post );

// update $_POST['return']
$_POST['return'] = add_query_arg( array('post_id' => $post_id), $_POST['return'] );

// return the new ID
return $post_id;
```

}

add_filter('acf/pre_save_post' , 'my_pre_save_post' );

Answer (score 0):

I was just a thought, but I have not tried.

you need / add functions in `wp-includes / query.php`

Such code:

```
function query_post($post_id) {
    $GLOBALS['wp_query'] = new WP_Query();
    return $GLOBALS['wp_query']->query($post_id);

}
```